# Onclick for arrays in JSON

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I'm retrieving data through an api, and creating a list using JS. I was wondering if it was possible to create a onclick function for every element in an array element of a JSON. The elements are being displayed, but nothing happens when I click them. Also, is it possible to pass on data in the JSON with this redirection to a new page?

My code is as follows:

```
var url = "https://api.nytimes.com/svc/movies/v2/reviews/all.json?api-key=b5f6bc931d6e446a998eb063a7c13d8e";
$.ajax({
    url: url,
    method: 'GET',
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function (data) {
        var data = data;
        details(data);
        for (var i = 0; i < Object.keys(data.results[0]).length; i++) {
            document.getElementById("movlist");
            var item = document.createElement('li');
            item.className = 'listele';
            var itempicdiv = document.createElement('div');
            itempicdiv.className = 'picdiv';
            var itempic = document.createElement('img');
            itempic.className = 'pic';
            itempic.src = data.results[i].multimedia.src;
            var itemnamediv = document.createElement('div');
            itemnamediv.className = 'namediv';
            var itemname = document.createTextNode(data.results[i].display_title);
            itemname.className = 'name';
            itempicdiv.appendChild(itempic);
            itemnamediv.appendChild(itemname);
            item.appendChild(itempicdiv);
            item.appendChild(itemnamediv);
            list.appendChild(item);
        }
    }
}).done(function (result) {
    console.log(result);
}).fail(function (err) {
    throw err;
});

function details(data) {
    for (var j = 0; j < Object.keys(data.results[0]).length; j++) {
        var t = data.results[j];
        t.onclick = function () {
            location.href = 'detail.html';
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You have a lot of errors in your code, so you need to open the console to check them then you can fix them. Ex: `Uncaught ReferenceError: i is not defined`  at `var t = data.results[i];` because `i` is not defined in this scope.

Comment: I've changed it to j. I've fixed that error. Still doesn't work.

Comment: This is not the only error you have a lot of them. so you should open your browser console to fix them, Ex: `ncaught ReferenceError: list is not defined`.

Comment: That's been added on the HTML side, which is why the error is appearing for you. My question is why the onclick function isn't working.

Comment: You need to fix your errors first, then go for the `onclick` function. for example `i < Object.keys(data.results[0]).length` this loop will work only for the first result. so this line `  itempic.src = data.results[i].multimedia.src;` will not work as expected.

Comment: Dear friend you cannot attach to `onlick` of js object. You can subscribe to `onlick` of HTML element like `<button>, <div>, <span>, <a>` etc ... And also why don't you use `jQuery` to generate those items instead vanillaJS ?

Comment: I fixed all the errors. [Link](https://pastebin.com/pXYD16LL). onclick still not working. :(

Comment: @codtex I tried using this: $(".listele").onclick = function() {
          window.location.href = 'detail.html';
        }
Still didn't work.

Comment: Well this won't work because this is not the right syntax. You would do `$(".listele").on('click', function() { window.location.href = 'detail.html'; }); ` and for dynamically generated elements you would like to do `$(document).on('click', '.listele', function() { window.location.href = 'detail.html'; }); `

Comment: This worked! Thank you! Is it possible to pass data from the JSON to the new page?

Comment: Well you can use `localStorage` or `cookies` to do that

Comment: @codtex I need to send data to the next page, from the JSON, depending on the item that has been clicked in the list. I have made a separate onclick function for every member in the list, but am not able to pass any parameters.

Comment: So you are opening a new page and you want to pass data to the server or ?

Comment: No no. I'm creating a new page, wherein I can display more details about the itemlist. But it will be different depending on what is clicked. I can't figure out how to extract data from the JSON depending on what item is clicked.